# For a joint distribution probability $X>Y$

Tags: probability

For a joint distribution $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is $P(Y>X)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \! \int_{-\infty}^y f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dx\,dy$? and if so for what types of r.vs

Comment: You have written down the integral for $\Pr(X\lt Y)$. Note that you have $x$ going up to $y$.

Comment: so its true? since ive seen it done before to find that proability a r.v is greater then another but ive never seen it proved or anything

Answer (score 2):

As Andre Nicolas points out, you've got the integral a bit backwards; rather,
$$
P(Y<X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{x} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dy\,dx,
$$
assuming of course that $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with the joint probability density function $f_{X,Y}$. This type of formula will not work if, for instance, one of the variables is discrete, or has discrete and continuous components.

Technically speaking, you would actually want to start off with
$$
\iint\limits_{D} f_{X,Y}\,dA,
$$
where $D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid y<x\}$; but, you can write this as an iterated integral, as above, by applying Tonelli's Theorem.

In the other cases that I mentioned, you would need to resort to measure-theoretic integrals rather than integrals against a density.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I originaly meant $P(Y>X)$. Can you prove it or show me a proof?

Comment: It is basically a definition - when we talk about the _joint distribution_ of $X$ and $Y$, what we are really talking about is the distribution of the random vector $(X,Y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. So, the probability of a given event is just the integral of the joint density function (that is, the density of $(X,Y)$) over all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ which are part of the event.